# display value of checkbox field in database, with php foreach loop

Tags: php, sql-server, types, checkbox

I am scratching my head a little.

I have a form with a checkbox that writes to a mssql database column `treated`.  This works perfectly and you can see the image of it below:

[image]

Originally I had this as data type `bit` but have now changed it to `char` in an attempt to fix my issue.

So my issue is this, When I query the rows in a foreach loop and echo the contents of the `treated` column it echo's 'on' for each row and not `0,on,0,on` as per the image.

[image]

if I echo the `bundles` column this does indeed echo out correctly `4,5,7,10`

Any ideas on the issue remembering that the field was populated by a checkbox? is it a checkbox issue, data type or?

Any help appreciated as always, seems like a simple issue but I just cant get it right.

Cheers,

**Update**

Data is retrieved using codeigniter:

so my model is:

```
function get_load_lines($ordernumber)
{

    $q = $this->db->query("
SELECT [CustomerOrderID]
      [treated]
  FROM [hammerhead].[dbo].[Customer_Order_Lines] 
  join [hammerhead].[dbo].[ProductList] 
  on [hammerhead].[dbo].[Customer_Order_Lines].product=[hammerhead].[dbo].[ProductList].[ProductCode]
  where [CustomerOrderID]='$ordernumber' and linestatus='current' and product>'0'
  ");
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        return $q->result_array();
    }
}
```

My COntroller is:

```
    function edit_order_lines() 
  {
     $postinfo = array();
      $data = array(
         'loadlines' => $this->sales_model->get_load_lines($this->input->post('ordernumber'))   
      );
        $this->load->view('sales/edit_order_lines',$data);
  }
```

any my view is:

```
<?php
$i=1;
foreach ($loadlines as $row)
{ 
//rest of code
$i++;
echo $row['treated'];
}
?>
```

Thanks,

Comment: We'll need to see your query, also I recommend using 1 and 0 (tinyint(1)) instead of 0 and on, good for indexing and for other calculations you might want to do later

Comment: Show the code with the `echo`s

Comment: Thanks Chen, how do I get a checkbox to write 1 and 0 rather than on as is currently happening?

Comment: Hi All, I have added my syntax above. I am using codeigniter framework for this. If you need anything else please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Thanks Chen, how do I get a checkbox to write 1 and 0 rather than on as is currently happening?

Change your `treated` to the following:

```
ALTER table yourtable MODIFY column treated tinyint(1);
```

Now when checked it gives `1` and when it isn't checked it gives `0`

Now you can do the following:

```
<?php
    foreach ($loadlines as $row)
    { 
        //rest of code
        echo $row['treated'];
    }
?>
```

It will give 1 or 0

Comment: Hi Kees, I am using odeigniter and wondering if that's not the issue. If I change to data type int(1), the checkbox writing to database fails with `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'on' to data type tinyint.` `on` being 2 characters long where tnyint allows 1? any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. you can't convert varchars like on to an integer like int or tinyint.